# Node ffmpeg - Square image to video image distortion

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a problem. I used this code and got a `640x640` video but its converted from a `1280x720` and that's why I get distorted images. What am I doing wrong? I tried different codecs but I have the same problem.
(My images res `640x640` )

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({
            source: './test/' + 0  + '/img%0d.jpg',
            nolog: false
        }).format('mp4')
            .size('640x640')
            .autopad()
            .videoCodec('libx264')

            .videoFilter('zoompan=d=60:');// 
        proc.save(path + 'video' + '.mp4', function (retcode, error) {
            console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
        });
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found setsar=1 filter :) 
and problem is resolved